# Angular Interceptors are overwritten and disappear

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have a core module in which I define two HTTP interceptors. Like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CoreInterceptor, multi: true },
        ...
    ],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

This works well. The interceptors are called in my entire application and do their job.
Now I wanted to extend a module of my application with another interceptor.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: EventInterceptor, multi: true },
        ...
    ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

As soon as I include the `EventInterceptor`, the interceptors from my `CoreModule` are no longer called. Of course I could now also include `BasicAuthInterceptor` and `CoreInterceptor` in my `ApplicationModule`. However, I would like to avoid that.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a stack blitz sample? I did it one for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-knkdmu?file=app%2Fcore.module.ts,app%2Fapp.module.ts,app%2Finterceptors.ts,app%2Ftest.module.ts

Comment: Did you import the HttpClientModule in the ApplicationModule? If so, it overrides other interceptors

Comment: @Alexander indeed I do import the `HttpClientModule`. But I need to do. Otherwise the interceptor isn't called